# The file “Siri” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: swift, ios10, xcode8, sirikit

I tried to integrate Siri kit to my app.
But got the error: `The file “Siri” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.` from ***Xcode 8(Mac: 10.11.6)***.
 I also added `Privacy - Siri Usage Description` to `plist` file of my app. 
The code to request authorization:

```
INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization { (status) in
      print("new status: \(status)")
}
```

The strange thing to me is in `General` tab I cannot see the Seri-kit to enable it. 
Please view the image for detail:
[image]
[image]